# No puedo guardar todo el archivo html

Tags: javascript, html

No puedo guardar el archivo html de manera completa.

Porfavor da click en el siguiente enlace

https://www.bitfinex.com/order_book/BTCUSD

despues usa el atajo CTRL+S y guarda el archivo en formato html , abre el archivo guardado y podras ver que solo hay un fragmento de la pagina.

Necesito saber el porque y si conoces alguna solucion tambien seria de ayuda.

Gracias  =D

Nota: no es algun ajax que funcione segun lo que se esta visualizando porque si te desconectas de internet y revisas el sitio (ya cargado) la informacion sigue ahi , inclusive si sombreas todo el sitio , lo copias y lo guardas , solo podras guardar un fragmento de el sitio¡¡ =S

Comment: En google chrome y firefox podrás ver el código fuente de un sitio web si agregas `view-source` antes de el enlance.

Comment: Si desactivas JS veras que no carga los datos. Son cargados dinámicamente una vez la pagina está cargada y por eso no puedes guardar el código fuente generado.
Puedes usar la extensión webdeveloper, que te permite guardar el código generado o hacer copipaste desde el inspector del navegador, boton derecho sobre la etiqueta `<html>` y copy outerHTML

Comment: Esta pregunta no parece ser sobre programación en el ámbito definido en el [help].

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que los `<div>` se van generando en la posición que estas dinámicamente y cuando intentas guardar la página solo se van a imprimir los que se han generado previamente en la web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si te fijas el primer `div` generado esta en la posición 0px:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si vas bajando vas a ver que el `div` de 0px desaparece.

En definitiva la clase `ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer` es la clave de todo este problema. Un grid hace que las celdas sean necesarias para llenarse en función de la posición de desplazamiento horizontal y vertical actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que hayas entendido cual era el problema.

Saludos!